# A +1, 10 Strength Dagger, or a mundane, higher Strength weapon?

Tags: brogue

This question concerns Brogue.

I can't remember what Strength each weapon requires to wield except daggers (10) and swords (14), but I'll make up an example.

Say I have two weapons with me, a weapon that requires 12 Strength to wield and is +1, and one that requires 13 Strength but is mundane (+0).

My question is, which one causes more damage? Is damage the only difference? Is there a chart or something that shows how each weapon differs from the rest, like a damage chart or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have adapted this [chart](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wvvzX4-qvhCf-y4BqYBTv7xskAHtacPZBfXhQIh-mjc/edit) to answer the question:

```
Weapon Name     Damage Roll (range)  Str req.  Notes 
                                      for +0
Dagger          1d2+2 (3-4)             10                  
Sword           1d4+5 (6-10)            14         
Broadsword      1d6+15 (14-22)          19         
Mace            1d13+17 (18-30)         16     2 turns
War Hammer      1d20+29 (30-50)         20     2 turns
Spear           1d2+3 (4-5)             13     Hits 2 in attack dir
War Pike        1d6+8 (9-15)            18     Hits 2 in attack dir
Axe             1d3+5 (6-9)             15     Hits all adjacent
War Axe         1d7+9 (10-17)           19     Hits all adjacent
Dart            1d3+1 (2-4)             10         
Incendiary Dart 1d2 (1-2)               12     Burns target
Javelin         3d3+2 (5-11)            15
```

Found in [this](http://brogue.createforumhosting.com/weapon-armor-penalties-bonuses-t224.html) thread of the Brogue forum.

Comment: So the only difference between, say, a mundane Spear and a +1 Spear is the Spear deals 1d2+3 damage, while the +1 Spear deals 1d2+4 damage?

Comment: and the +1 spear should have 1 less str requirement

Comment: @yx. *Could* have 1 less strength. It'd only have 1 less if you personally enchanted it - naturally enchanted items do not have modified strength requirements.